# Using aliases for zero downtime with time indices

Tags: elasticsearch

According to [Index Aliases and Zero downtime](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html#index-aliases), the best way to update index mappings consists in adding a version to the index name and copying the old documents into the new indices while updating the alias to point to the new version indices.

That's fine for normal data, but I can't make it work for time indices.

Let's say I have event data that I want to split in monthly indices: [`events-201601`, `events-201602`, ...].

According to the docs, I should add the version infix to those indices. That would result in: [`events-v1-201601`, `events-v1-201602`, ...].

Now I would need to add an alias pointing to all those indices. I can do so, but when new monthly indices come out (i.e. next month), the alias I just created will remain outdated, since it won't have the new index `events-v1-201603`.

What would be the correct approach to manage this?

Comment: I'd suggest using [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) where you can specify an alias to be added to all newly created indices.

Comment: @Val unfortunately that's not possible because the placeholder for the alias (e.g. `"{index}-alias"`) does not allow to operate with the index name. So I can create an index `events-v1-201601` but I can't create a (shorter) alias `events-201601` using a template.

Comment: The alias can be named whatever you want, it doesn't have to have the `{index}` name in it.